# Video play pause button animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, video, html5-video

When cursor is hovered on video when it's playing, then animation of word 'pause' is fine, and when I toggle it - it's fine too, but when video is stopped, cursor is removed from video and again hovered on it - then my animation of word 'play'  is failed.

Tried to set different behavior when video is playing and stopped:

```
var x = myVid.play();
var x = true;

if ( x ) {

}

var y = myVid.pause();
var y = true;

if ( y ) {

}
```

How can I fix it or any ideas would be great.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm8La/1/)

[live example](http://beardhouse.com.ua/#/informacia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on hover you should check if the video is playing or stopped.
Also, it'll be easier if you did the same for the click.

something like below (i did replace your slide left with opacity)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("as");
    myVid=document.getElementById('infoVideo');

    $('#video-mask').hover(function (){

      $(this).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 200 ,function(){
        if(!myVid.paused){
            $('#video-play').animate({opacity : '0'}, 200);
            $('#video-pause').animate({opacity : '1'}, 200);

        }else{
            $('#video-play').animate({opacity : '1'}, 200);
            $('#video-pause').animate({opacity : '0'}, 200);
        }
      });
      },function(){
        $(this).animate({ opacity: '0' }, 200);
    });

    $('#video-mask').on('click', function(){
        if(!myVid.paused){
            myVid.pause();
            $('#video-play').animate({opacity : '1'}, 200);
            $('#video-pause').animate({opacity : '0'}, 200);
        }else{
            myVid.play();
            $('#video-play').animate({opacity : '0'}, 200);
            $('#video-pause').animate({opacity : '1'}, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tnx, perfect solution - exactly what I need!